# completion blocks in SpriteKit never called

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I currently have some completion blocks that are supposed to be executed once a swipe gesture has completed.  I put break points inside the functions that are supposed to be called in the completion block but they are never triggered.  The swipe gesture works, I'm not sure why the completion blocks aren't being called.  Here is my code:

```
    import SpriteKit


let plankName = "woodPlank"

class PlankScene: SKScene {

  var plankWood : SKSpriteNode?

  var plankArray : [SKSpriteNode] = []





  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    enumerateChildNodes(withName: plankName) {
      node, stop in
      self.plankWood = node as? SKSpriteNode

      let swipeRight : UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(PlankScene.swipedRight))

      swipeRight.direction = .right

      view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)


    }

  }



  func swipedRight(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

    if sender.direction == .right {

        //The functions in this completion block are never called
      swipeAndAddPlank(completion: {
        self.addPlank(completion: {
        self.movePlanksUp()
        })

      })
    }
  }


  func swipeAndAddPlank(completion: (()->Void)?) {

    let moveOffScreenRight = SKAction.moveTo(x: 400, duration: 0.5)

    let nodeFinishedMoving = SKAction.removeFromParent()

    plankWood?.run(SKAction.sequence([moveOffScreenRight,nodeFinishedMoving]))


  }


  //This function never called
  func addPlank(completion: (()->Void)?) {
    let newPlank = plankWood?.copy() as! SKSpriteNode
    newPlank.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -259)
    plankArray.append(newPlank)
    print(plankArray.count)
    addChild(newPlank)


  }

    //This function never called
  func movePlanksUp() {
    for node:SKSpriteNode in plankArray {
      node.run(SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 50), duration: 0.10))
    }
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

`swipeAndAddPlank` does not contain a call to the `completion` block passed to it. Same for `addPlank`. You need to insert a call to `completion()`.

You might be looking for `SKAction.runBlock`. Something like

```
let completionAction = SKAction.runBlock({ completion() })
```

Then add `completionAction` to the sequence of actions plankWood is set to run.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for! But for some strange reason I get an error "Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type '() -> Void'"

Comment: This is what I used:     let completionAction = SKAction.runBlock(addPlank{completion!()})